# How to update Fragment TextView from FragmentActivity when finish a AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an activity extends from `FragmentActivity`, and I have four TABS of `Fragments`, I have `AsyncTask` in main `FragmentActivity`to get load data from a server, so, I want to update each Fragment data when complete the AsyncTask function on parent FragmentActivity, since I'm using `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` all the Fragment's UI loading when starts the Activity with blank data, so, I want to update the each fragment fields (TextView) with the data getting from AsyncTask, How I can update. Appreciate your help. The below code using for get Fragment

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Fragment fragmenthome =  new HomeFragment();                
            return fragmenthome;                
        case 1:
            Fragment fragmentdiagnosis =  new DiagnosisFragment();              
            return fragmentdiagnosis;
        case 2:
            Fragment fragmentcareplan =  new CareplanFragment();                
            return fragmentcareplan;
        case 3:             
            Fragment fragmentnote =  new NoteFragment();                
            return fragmentnote;
        case 4:
            Fragment fragmenttask =  new TaskFragment();                
            return fragmenttask;                    
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And here is a sample Fragment

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText("Comming Soon...");
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

here is the main Activity 
public class PatientActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_patient);
    // AsyncTask function calling
```

}

Comment: the code is basic Activity with TABS of Fragments, using SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

Comment: you can handle in onResume() using the condition if the onPost gets executed then mark the flag as true and do your update code there

Comment: actually, I'm retrieving data from a Parse Object via Callback function, that callback in a AsyncTask of main activity (FragmentActivity), I want to update the Parse object data in to 4 Tabs (Fragments)  TextView fields

Comment: you can use create an `interface` and override it's method in all fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Create method in fragment which updates the text in text view,access fragment method from the fragment activity.

```
DemoFragment demo_frag = (DemoFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Demo_Fragment");
 demo_frag.updateTextView();
```

Comment: may I know what is this "Demo_Fragment" and where to find it?

Comment: "Demo_Fragment" is the tag which you give when u are adding/replacing the fragment.

Comment: I'm calling the fragment like this,   @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   switch (position) {
   case 0:
    Fragment fragmenthome =  new HomeFragment();    
    return fragmenthome;    
   case 1: